# ERROR: AndroidManifest.xml is corrupt when upload APK

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play, android-manifest, apk

I spent many hours searching answer to my question, but unfortunately didn't found it.
I have read about similar questions, but there is no answer for me.

([Error with Uploading APK to Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626194/error-with-uploading-apk-to-google-play))

([Error message I got when I went to upload to the playstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972342/error-message-i-got-when-i-went-to-upload-to-the-playstore)) and so on.

And this is my problem:

When i upload my Apk to Google Play i have this error:

```
Upload failed
Your APK cannot be analyzed using 'aapt dump badging'. Error output:
Failed to run aapt dump badging:
W/ResourceType( 5477): Bad XML block: header size 28024 or total size 1702240364 
is larger than data size 2718
ERROR: AndroidManifest.xml is corrupt
```

> [image]

In Google Play market i have uploaded earlier version of this app, but it is in Alpha testing version.

I have treied:

1. Clean + Rebuild (run on Emulator/Real device)
2. Creating new project and transferring the code in it.
3. Removing and putting different elements in AndroidManifest.xml
4. All texts are in string.xml and android:icon is in all drawable folders.

I use extension of the support library - ActionBarSherlock(http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.htv.bg"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_app"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name="com.htv.bg.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.htv.bg.HomeMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.htv.bg.HOMEMENU" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.htv.bg.HtvVideo"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.htv.bg.HTVVIDEO" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.htv.bg.InstalVPlayer"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.htv.bg.INSTALVPLAYER" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Can someone please help out to fix this problem!

Comment: Yes, i'm sure about that :(

Comment: did you remove the space before <?xml... (first line), this has screwed things up for me before

Comment: Yes, i don't have any space before
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: You should check that all you resource files use low letters only.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply guys.
The mistake was in me, not in the code.
I followed this tutorial and now everything is fine:
(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gpxM0ffAvok)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this tutorial and now everything is fine:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gpxM0ffAvok

Comment: This video is not available, Could you please let me know the steps?

Comment: This is why you shouldn't post links and should share your solution instead